# Packet Get Queued Forever with the eBPF `sk_skb_stream_verdict` Program

Tags: tcp, ebpf

I am currently trying to use the eBPF sk_skb_stream_verdict program to redirect TCP packet, the architecture looks like the following:

```
client <--[key=0]--> proxy <--[key=1]--> server
```

The server is a TCP server written in Go, it simply echo back all packet it received.

The proxy is a TCP proxy that send all packet it received from client to server, and from server to client respectively using 2 go routines.

My bpf program is as follows:

```c
//go:build ignore

#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_endian.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 8080
#define PROXY_PORT 8081

// client <--[key=0]--> proxy <--[key=1]--> server

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_SOCKMAP);
    __uint(max_entries, 32);
    __type(key, __u32);
    __type(value, __u32); // socket FD
} sockmap SEC(".maps");

SEC("sockops/prog")
int sockops_prog(struct bpf_sock_ops *skops) {
    switch (skops->op) {
    case BPF_SOCK_OPS_PASSIVE_ESTABLISHED_CB: // SYN-ACK
        if (skops->local_port == PROXY_PORT) {
            __u32 key = 0;
            bpf_sock_map_update(skops, &sockmap, &key, BPF_ANY);
        }
        break;
    case BPF_SOCK_OPS_ACTIVE_ESTABLISHED_CB: // SYN
        if (bpf_ntohl(skops->remote_port) == SERVER_PORT) {
            __u32 key = 1;
            bpf_sock_map_update(skops, &sockmap, &key, BPF_ANY);
        }
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

SEC("sk_skb/stream_verdict/prog")
int sk_skb_stream_verdict_prog(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
    int res;

    if (skb->local_port == PROXY_PORT) {
        // doesn't work
        // res = bpf_sk_redirect_map(skb, &sockmap, 0, BPF_F_INGRESS);

        // works
        res = bpf_sk_redirect_map(skb, &sockmap, 1, 0);
        return res;
    }

    if (bpf_ntohl(skb->remote_port) == SERVER_PORT) {
        // doesn't work
        // res = bpf_sk_redirect_map(skb, &sockmap, 1, BPF_F_INGRESS);

        // works
        res = bpf_sk_redirect_map(skb, &sockmap, 0, 0);
        return res;
    }

    return SK_DROP;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

When I use the `bpf_sk_redirect_map` function with the flag `0` to bypass all packets from client to server and from server to client directly (without the proxy application's help), it works without any error.

However, when I try to set the flag to `BPF_F_INGRESS` so the packet can be processed by the proxy, it behaves weirdly.

I use the `nc`(netcat) command as the client to start a TCP connection with the [B]proxy[/B]:

- When the 1st packet "aaaaa" is sent, the client immediately received the "aaaaa" back.
- When the 2nd packet "bbbbb" is sent, the packet seems to be queued forever.
- When the 3rd packet "ccccc" is sent, the client immediately received the "bbbbb" and "ccccc" back together.

I've tried to use [cilium/pwru](https://github.com/cilium/pwru) to trace the packet, and it seems like when the 1st packet "aaaaa" is sent, the `sk_psock_verdict_recv` function was called (which I think is where the bpf receive logic located).

But when the 2nd packet "bbbbb" was sent, `sk_psock_verdict_recv` never happen until the 3rd packet is sent. Here is the full pwru log. https://gist.github.com/justin0u0/cda151b658f5a8eef784b3c058a6c75f

I'm using Linux archlinux 6.1.52, the server and the client is started in the Docker engine using the [host network](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/).

The code is available on the [Github repo](https://github.com/justin0u0/bpf-tcp-proxy-sample).

Any help or advice would be appreciated, thank you!